# iMovie export to Ogg Theora?

Tags: imovie

After I finish editing a movie with iMovie '09 under Mac OS X 10.6.4, is there a way to export the final product to Ogg Theora format? OR, is there a way to convert an already exported movie to Ogg Theora easily?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As part of [Dive Into HTML5](http://diveintohtml5.org), Mark Pilgrim gives two options:

- [Encoding Ogg Video With Firefogg](http://diveintohtml5.org/video.html#firefogg)
- [Batch Encoding Ogg Video With ffmpeg2theora](http://diveintohtml5.org/video.html#ffmpeg2theora)

One or both of those should work for you.

Comment: These links are dead...

Answer (score 1):

Just install the [XiphQT Quicktime plugin](http://xiph.org/quicktime/)... allows any of the Quicktime-based OS X video players/editors, including iMovie, to export to Theora.